# Setting listview ItemContainerStyle in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a `ListView` which rows alternate color:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RowColorStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}" AlternationCount="2">
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Now I have set listview `ItemContainerStyle` as below:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lvi_MouseDown" />
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove"  Handler="lvi_MouseMove" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The problem now is that listview define `ItemContainerStyle` body more than one time so I am trying to move `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}"` within the last defined `ItemContainerStyle` section just implemented but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking but you can base a `Style` on another one using the `BasedOn` property:

```
<ListView AlternationCount="2">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lvi_MouseDown" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove"  Handler="lvi_MouseMove" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I like your solution more than mine as yours separates the row alternation color from the rest of event setters.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it by doing below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="alternatingStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lvi_MouseDown" />
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove"  Handler="lvi_MouseMove" />
            </Style.Setters>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"  Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}"
                      AlternationCount="2">
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

@mm8 solution also works using BasedOn.